# Not possible to change div background with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following [Squarespace website](http://hethuisvandelingerie.squarespace.com). You can login to the site by clicking visitor access and typing in the code.

I'd like to change the background of the website by using the followng background image:
https://hethuisvandelingerie.squarespace.com/assets/bgs/bg8.png

I tried to do this with a CSS code to add a background image to the div with ID "canvas". This is the code I used:

```
#canvas{background-image: url('assets/bgs/bg8.png');}
```

However, this code does not seem to add the background image?

Any of you have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Do not share a link but put directly your code here. Please edit your post or it will be certainly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `site.css`, look for this entry and remove the `background` line from `#main`. You've applied the background image to `#canvas` but `#main` is displaying over `#canvas` and `#main`'s background is covering the background image applied to `#canvas`

```
#main {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! <br> Indeed, I had to remove the backgrounds of the main & also the header who were covering up my background image of the canvas (containing both header & main). Using the following code, I was able to add the background image & disable the white background color on my smartphone website. It's looking good now, thanks for the help! `@media screen and ( max-width: 640px ){ #canvas { background-image: url('assets/bgs/bg7.png'); } #main { background:none; } #header { background:none; } } `

Comment: @BarrieO awesome! no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on your `main` wrapped on your `#canvas` div. Try to use the same CSS code. Hope it helps!

```
main {
   background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/58639728d2b857b308f66598/404/assets/bgs/bg8.png)
}
```

Comment: Hi Henrique, thanks for your reply. This works, but it's not totally what I want since I also want to have my mobile header with the same background. That way, I have a #main with the background, but when changing my window to mobile or tablet resolution, my header is just plain white. Therefore, I'd like to change the background of my canvas as this contains both my #header, as my #main. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Nice! So you should use @media queries to apply the background just on the proper screen sizes!

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Try removing the single quotes from the path

```
#canvas{background-image: url(assets/bgs/bg8.png);}
```

If that doesn't work

> - Make sure that you entered the right path.
> - Double check that the id of the element is in fact `canvas`

*(I personally think it's a less than optimal name since canvas is now also a class)*

Comment: Hi Oscar, tried it but did not work :(. Also tried double quotes, but no succes with that. Thanks for your answer!